# S3 TransferUtility.Upload() Network Failure before or during locks file

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading a file into Amazon S3 using the .net sdk. Calling `TransferUtility.Upload()` works quite well. In testing i have discovered that this method locks the file being uploaded, so i make a copy since my application still needs access to the file during the upload.

In testing network failure scenarios, i have discovered that TransferUtility does not release lock on a file it tries to upload when it fails due to connectivity. It throws an `AmazonServiceException` which i handle, and then still won't release the file despite both exiting a using block, or calling `.Dispose()` myself.

All research has yielded nothing about handling network failure other than mentioning that if `.Upload()` spawns a 'multi-part upload' it might not always be able to clear itself. But i'm experiencing this issue with files of any size, not just large ones.

here is my code:

```
private Response PutDocument(String CloudPath, String UploadFilePath)
    {
        var oResponse = new Response(true);
        try
        {
            using (IAmazonS3 s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client())
            {
                using (TransferUtility filexfer = new TransferUtility(s3Client))
                {
                     filexfer.Upload(UploadFilePath, BucketName, CloudPath);
                     oResponse.Message = "Upload Successful";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
        {
            oResponse.OK = false;
            oResponse.Message = "Error when connecting to AWS: ";

            if (ex.ErrorCode != null && (ex.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") ||
                ex.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
            {
                oResponse.Message += ex.ErrorCode + ": " + "Please check the provided AWS Credentials in the web.config file.";
            }
            else
            {
                oResponse.Message += "Caught Exception: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonServiceException ex)
        {
            oResponse.OK = false;
            oResponse.Message = "Network Error when connecting to AWS: " + ex.Message;
        }

        //delete temp file
        //throws IO exception when file is locked due to network outage
        File.Delete(UploadFilePath);
        return oResponse;
    }
```

So it doesn't seem like it should expected behavior for TransferUtility to keep a file locked after an upload has failed. Does anyone have experience with this and/or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered creating your own read-only FileStream that allows concurrent readers? The TransferUtility should be able to use an InputStream rather than the file path. That would allow your application to still read the file, unless it needs exclusive access. Also that would allow yourself to close the stream on failures/completion, rather than hoping that TransferUtility does so.

```
using (var tu = new TransferUtility("id", "key", RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
using (var fs = new FileStream("C:\\MyFile.xyz", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    tu.Upload(fs, "mybucket", "mykey");
}
```

Comment: I fully expect TransferUtility to lock the file while it's uploading, i don't need any access to the file until after the failure. Sorry if i'm misunderstanding, are you suggesting i should read the entire file into memory and then pass that to the upload? My files could be up to 30MB in size... I think that seems dangerous when i can have many concurrent uploads going on my application server?

Comment: Not suggesting you read it into memory, simply creating your own stream and pass it to the TransferUtility. That was you control the filesharing meanwhile (others can read at the same time, if necessary), and you control the locking itself. This way TransferUtility does not do any locking. I've added an example to my post.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and that appears to release the file. I'll have to do some further testing but this looks to be a good workaround. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

On failure, try calling TransferUtility.AbortMultipartUploads().  That may clean up the file locks.

Take a look at the documentation here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility_Upload_3.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have tried this already and it did not work.